# Mysql - Prevent duplicate entry for incremental value in a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, locking

My site hosted in a shared hosting. It's a POS application (PHP, Codeigniter). It has several users. Everyone is generating invoice. Invoice number is incremental. That is when a user submit a invoice form, it fetches the last invoice number then increment it by one and then create a new row with new invoice number. This process some time (very rarely) duplicate invoice number generated when users submits the form pretty much same time.

One possible way is that make invoice unique. But if it happens again, user will see an exception or formatted error message.

I don't want show error to my users. Because when they submit the invoice form , it contains sales information that they have written. If they loose it because of this warning, they feel disturbed. AJAX will not work. Direct submit is working here(for invoice submission ).

Can SQL lock be applied for this situation? I have no idea about SQL locking.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Use an auto increment primary key.

Comment: Auto increment Primary key is already there. I'm using another column(int) as for invoice number.

Comment: Yes, codeigniter have a function to do this. https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/transactions.html

Comment: @sukalogika can transaction prevent another user to read the latest invoice number while other user is writing the table in the same time? I want to prevent reading (when writing invoice), because if user can not read, duplicate value ca not be produced.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is not performance an inefficient way to do would be something like
Insert your invoice number as null/zero and have another query update that

like

```
INSERT INTO invoices (id, invoice_number) VALUES (10001, null);
UPDATE invoices SET invoice_number = id WHERE invoice_number IS NULL;
```

For locks you can look into [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) that would lock the last read row, and also inserts from other connections are also blocked but its better you try it on your DB as this depends on your Mysql version and isolation levels set.